# scroll into view triggers before the new table page has painted (event handlers with side effects)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, single-page-application

**Feature:** user history table with pagination (table data loads in one API call and FE handles pagination).
**Side effect:** scroll to table header on table page change.

#### **Issue:**

if the scroll triggers before the new table page has painted (and the table is a different height) the scroll doesn't work.

It seems like either Option A or B could work but I'm not sure how well across OS/Browser envs.
Does anyone have exp with this ...or the pros and cons of a timeout vs promise to solve this problem? Option C?

```
const onPageChange = page => {
    // Original
    dispatch(setCurrentPage(page));
    scrollToRef(tableHeaderRef, 'start');

    // Option A
    // dispatch(setCurrentPage(page));
    // setTimeout(() => scrollToRef(tableHeaderRef, 'start'), 100);

    // Option B (does this need a catch?)
    // new Promise(resolve => {
    //   dispatch(setCurrentPage(page));
    //   resolve();
    // }).then(() => scrollToRef(tableHeaderRef, 'start'));

    // Option C?
};
```